# подсветка в php-файлах в pycharm community edition

Tags: php, pycharm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить раскраску php-файлов в pycharm CE? Сейчас они выводятся как plain text.

Comment: редактировать через phpstorm

Comment: спасибо, это довольно очевидно. у phpstorm нет CE-версии и есть еще некоторые причины, по которым было бы удобно использовать pycharm. вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986720/pycharm-is-community-edition-able-to-highlight-css-javascript в комментариях есть решение аналогичного вопроса для css-файлов, может быть есть такой же файл разметки кода для php?

Comment: может быть есть плагин для подсветки php файлов надо гуглить.